# How to render vuetify 3 snackbar slot in unit test with jest

Tags: jestjs, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

Does anyone know how i can test the actions slot from a vuetify 3 snackbar?
In the first example from the official documentation you can add a button to a snackbar https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/snackbars/
In my unit test only the snackbar is rendered.

**UiMesssage.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="text-center">
    <v-snackbar v-model="show" vertical centered :color="getType()" :timeout="getTimeout(getType())">
      {{ getMessage() }}
      <template #actions>
        <v-btn color="indigo" variant="text" @click="removeErrorMessage()"> {{ closeButtonText }} </v-btn>
      </template>
    </v-snackbar>
  </div>
</template>
```

**Unit Test**

```
import { VueWrapper, mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify';

const vuetify = createVuetify();
let wrapper: VueWrapper;

async function createWrapper() {
  wrapper = mount(UiMessage, {
    propsData: { closeButtonText },
    global: {
      plugins: [vuetify],
    },
  });
  await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();
  return wrapper;
}

test('Check close button text.', async () => {
  wrapper = await createWrapper();
  console.log(wrapper.html());
  const buttonText = wrapper.find('.v-btn').text();
  expect(buttonText).toBe(closeButtonText);
});
```

**wrapper.html()**

```
  <div class="text-center">
      <v-snackbar modelvalue="true" vertical="" centered="" color="" timeout="2000"> </v-snackbar>
    </div>
```